# ghostscript annotation conversion

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert from pdf to pdf/a using version 9.19 on win server 2012r2.

commandline:
"D:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin\gswin64c" -dPDFA -dNOOUTERSAVE -dColorConversionStrategy=/sRGB -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o target.pdf -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2 "PDFA_def.ps" source.pdf

For a lot of files I get 
"Annotation set to non-printing, not permitted in PDF/A, aborting conversion"

Using Acrobat Pro conversion, it converts non printing annotations without problems.

What may I need to look for in PDFA_def.ps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to look for in pdfa_def.ps, since that is just a template for the additional information required to produce a PDF/A file.

Your problem is that your annotation is not valid for inclusion in a PDF/A file, non-printing annotations are not permitted in PDF/A. To create a PDF/A file from such an input, either the annotation must be removed, or it must be set to print. Ghostscript's pdfwrite device cannot know which one you want.

However, you can change the PDFACompatibilityPolicy; the default value is 0 which will include the offending feature, and produce a non-PDF/A file. You can try changing it to 1 instead which will ignore the feature. I'm not in a position to test this right now (I'm heading for an airport) but it ought to work.

Obviously I don't know what Acrobat does in this case, but it must do something similar, or produce an invalid file. At least Ghostscript gives you the choice.

Comment: Adobe pro 9 flattens non-printing annotations into page content. If I understand correctly, gswin64c doesn't have that kind of logic built in. I do need real pdfa/1b as a result so I'll use Adobe Pro instead. It is not that fast as ghostscript and the preflight has a memory leak so it stops after 10000 or so documents. The preflight batch processing in subsequent versions is even slower. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Correction: Adobe pro 9 flattens non-printing annotations or removes them.